# Replace characters between quotes with the first character using SED

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I need help with the following:

I have a csv with rows like:

```
a,b,c,d,"e,f,g",h,i
j,"k,l",m,n,"o,p",q
```

I need to select all the rows but only include the first character between the quotes. The result should look like:

```
a,b,c,d,e,h,i
j,k,m,n,o,q
```

This is for a shell script. So far I only have this:

```
sed 's/".*"//' xxx.csv
```

which gives

```
a,b,c,d,,h,i

j,,q
```

I also tried

```
sed 's/"// ; s/,.*"//' xxx.csv
```

and got this

```
a,h,i

j,q
```

SO I am not sure what to add in the replace section of the SED command to keep the characters I need.

Comment: Format code please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this sed one-liner a try:

```
sed 's/"\([^",]\+\)[^"]*"/\1/g;s/,\+/,/g' file
```

### Explanation:

We do the substitution in two steps:

- replace `"foo,bar,baz"` with `foo`
- replace continuous commas with a single comma

### Test

With your example:

```
kent$  cat f
a,b,c,d,"e,f,g",h,i
j,"k,l",m,n,"o,p",q

kent$  sed 's/"\([^",]\+\)[^"]*"/\1/g;s/,\+/,/g' f
a,b,c,d,e,h,i
j,k,m,n,o,q
```

Comment: @stephanmg in the test I was using the gnu sed

Comment: I have BSD sed, so maybe write it in the answer that GNU sed is used or required.

Comment: @stephanmg I don't have bsd sed, but perhaps you need to add a `-e` or something like that? the man page should tell you. The command, at least the `'s/....'` just BREs, should work for all seds.

Comment: Actually for OSX sed it does not work. Will see how I can make it work.

Comment: @stephanmg the question is tagged with "linux"

Comment: Oh @Kent sorry. I did not see this. Anyways here is the ported version to OSX sed from your answer: `sed -E 's/"([^",]+)[^"]*"/\1/g;s/,\+/,/g'  YOUR_FILE`.

Comment: @stephanmg thx. oh, the uppercase "E"... I just remembered with an "e". for gnu sed, the `-E` will make sed use ERE.